# Random Windows application crashes on Windows Server Hyper-V Core 2012

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

We're having some issues with our Hyper-V Core 2012 R2 installation on a HP DL360G8.

We have an identical server with Hyper-V Core 2012 (not R2) that does not have these issues.

When **logging off** from the physical server/via remote desktop, we **sometimes** get this error:

```
Configure-SMRemoting.exe - Application Error : The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142). Click OK to close the application.
```

We've also once or twice seen a "memory could not be read" error mentioning LoginUI.exe (another Windows app in System32) but have been unable to get an exact description.

It's rather worrying to get such errors on a fresh install of Hyper-V 2012 R2. 
Is this even anything to worry about?

Things we've done:

- Memtest86+, no memory errors
- Checksummed the file that is crashing with the one in the verified correct ISO, files match
- Server firmware upgrade to latest firmware of all present hardware, no visible changes
- Remade the RAID5 array , no change
- Reinstalled a few times, no change
- Reinstall without applying Windows updates after, no change

Comment: Have you checked Event Viewer for anything related to this?

Comment: Yes, we did. Nothing related in the event viewer..

Comment: Yup! It just has the application error, nothing else sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you install all the HP Driver on the G8?

Default install of Hyper-V will not help you install the other miss Driver.

Comment: Drivers for Hyper-V Core 2012 R2? I genuinely wasn't aware there were any. I'll definitely check that out, thanks!